# How is the tuning-word of a DDS sent and coded?

Tags: dds

I have read that a [DDS](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9850.pdf) have two inputs one for master clock another for the tuning word. By processing these two inputs the DDS generates the output waveform at a desired frequency.

And if I'm not wrong we need to send this tuning word to the DDS via its SPI interface.

But I cannot find information about the tuning word and is a little confusing.

What I mean is when we program a micro-controller, we code and compile and upload the data to it. And we do the coding part by using lets say C language we know what instructions do what.

But when it comes the DDS, how is the tuning word is sent/uploaded and how it is coded? Do we send it through an IDE? I have no picture about it. Can someone simplify this and give maybe an example how it is done.

---

That sequence with FQ UD CLKIN W CLK looks complicated to me. Is that about how SPI functions? It also seems DDS has no memory -- does it need that sequence nonstop as an input? The articles I found were too advanced for me. That's why I'm asking primitive questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at page 10 and further in the AD9850 DDS datasheet to see in what sequence the data needs to be presented to the DDS. Often a microcontroller is used to generate the signals as described in this datasheet.

It is similar to how you would write data to a memory chip. A certain sequence must be observed. This DDS is not very different in that respect.

I suggest to first familiarize yourself with the [concept of communication over SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface) and then look at the details of how that works on this DDS.

SPI just describes how the (data) bits get from A to B. The FQ, UD, CLKIN etc.. are just **names** for the registers in the DDS.

*It also seems DDS has no memory needs that sequence nonstop as an input?*

Fortunately the DDS does have memory, although they're called **registers** in essence these are just small memories. The DDS would be unable to function in a useful way without it. When you write settings, it uses those until you write new values or you switch the DDS off (obviously).\

There are some projects available on [using an Arduino with the AD9850](http://www.vwlowen.co.uk/arduino/AD9850-waveform-generator/AD9850-waveform-generator.htm)